# JavaScript - create links from user data provided in HTML textarea

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is, dynamically create clickable links from user provided textarea data, first being saved to the local machine using localStorage. User data is provided in the following format:

a|aa,
c|cc,
e|ee,

a,c,e are the labels for the links
aa,cc,ee are the links themselves

example of final output:

`<a href="aa" />a</a>`
`<a href="cc" />c</a>`
`<a href="ee" />e</a>`

Step 1: Save data to localStorage in a format that will later be used to create 2 separate arrays.

This is what I've done so far for step 1 (not sure it's correct)

// remove white space and carriage returns

`textToSave = textToSave.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"").trim();`

// replace | from user data with =>

`var textToSaveArrayFormat = textToSave.replace(/(\|)/g, "=>");`

// store data to localSorage

`localStorage.setItem("appLinkConfig" ,JSON.stringify(textToSaveArrayFormat));`

Step 2: Retrieve data from localStorage and create 2 arrays from that data

`URLLabels = ["a", "b", "c"];`

`URLOptions = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];`

For step 2 I start with

// get local storage app link config data

`var appLinksObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("appLinkConfig"));`
`console.log(appLinksObj);`

which returns

`a=>aa,c=>cc,e=>ee,`

From this I need to create my 2 arrays and this is where I'm stuck.

Step 3: I'm currently doing this with hardcoded arrays in my script, but would like to do it with the array data created in step 1 and 2.

```
// Object created
var obj = {};
  
// Using loop to insert key
// URLOptions in Object
for(var i = 0; i < URLLabels.length; i++){
    obj[URLLabels[i]] = URLOptions[i];
}

// Printing object
for (var URLLabels of Object.keys(obj)) {

    lnk.innerHTML += "<a href=\'" + URLLabels + "' target\='" + hotDeck + "'\>" + obj[URLLabels] + "</a>";

}
```

hotDeck is a flag I'm using to target one of two frames  (returns the ID of those frames) contained in the page.

Thanks in advance for your help - please be gentle, I've been away from coding for a long time due to illness and coding again now to help my recovery. I'd be very grateful to solve this problem.

Comment: What part(s) of what you want to do do you need help with?  What have you tried to solve those part(s)?

Comment: It will help if you could define what `URLLabels` & `hotdeck` are.

Comment: Thanks for your questions and sorry for any confusion - I've updated my post to answer thanks.

Comment: Why do you create two arrays (`URLLabels` and `URLOptions`) instead of using an array of objects (`"label": "option"`)?

Comment: Because I have a brain injury and now struggle to remember how things are done - it was just a solution I came up with at the time... I'm learning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are expecting. try the snippet on the console as i am not able to aceess `localStorage` property in the code snippet

```js
var input = 'a|aa, c|cc, e|ee';
var output = input.split(',').map(str => str.split('|'));
window.localStorage.setItem('appLinkConfig', JSON.stringify(output));
var config = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('appLinkConfig'));
var result = config.map(([text, href]) => `<a href="${href.trim()}">${text.trim()}</a>`).join(' ')
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, thank you. I just need to add a var to the mix and I'm done ;) I tried this <a href="${href.trim()}"  + "target='" + hotDeck + "'"> but this as I guess you will realise doesn't work.. I get this <a href="aa"  + "target='" + hotDeck + "'">a</a>. Can you please advice? Thanks again.